# Reuse select columns in oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

In my package, i do a select query in many places with different where conditions but with same list of columns. Like below.

```
Select a_1, a_2, a_3, ..... a_100 from table where <condition>
```

If there is a new a_101 i want to include in select, i have to edit all the places this select query is used manually and there are lot of selects just like this.

My question is, Is there a way we can define all columns as one variable and use that in select? Something like this.

```
declare
  v_columns varchar2(500 byte);
begin
  v_columns := 'a_1, a_2, a_3....... a_100'
  select v_columns from table;
end;
```

This way, if i want to add a new column like a_101, I just change in one place, the varialble declaration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many places? Surely not 1000's... just edit them. Get a good editor that has a search-and-replace function - e.g. replace `a_100` with `a_100,a_101` maybe.

Comment: Thats what i am doing right now and intending to do if nobody knows any other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way would be to define a view and then select * from that.

So if you had table with columns 1 to 30
but you are regularly selecting the even ones.

Create a view called which does select Column2, column4,...Column30 From SomeTable

then to reuse in your other queries do
Select * from SomeTableEvenColumns where ....

Comment: This select statement is in a procedure and it does several other things like copying into temporary tables etc. Select * will break the code if there is any new column defined in table but not in temporary table or TYPE with TABLE OF etc

Comment: I am trying to avoid 'Select * from'. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Jeevan Tony is talking about defining a view and selecting * from that, not selecting * from a table.